# will data store in my wallet or on the DApp's Database

Tags: web3js, metamask, wallets

If I create a account with my Ethereum wallet on other web3.0 app will data store in my wallet or on the DApp's Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an account and it hasn't made any transactions yet, and it has not been sent funds to, in other words, if it has not been used in the blockchain, then it does not yet exist in the  blockchain. It exists in your wallet and you should create a backup in case you lose access to your wallet, by writing down the seed phrases on a paper and saving it in a secure place, and/or use a cold wallet to store it.

The history of the transactions sent to and from your address are saved in the blockchain itself, in the "DApp's Database" as you call it, which is simply the smart contract storage in the blockchain.

All transactions and events are saved in the blockchain itself. Some wallets decide to save/cache some information locally as well, like balance, etc. But they aways comunicate with the blockchain for updates.